# Error while moving old database out of the way

Tags: update-manager

Every time I try to run `sudo apt-get update`, I get this error message:

```
** (appstreamcli:9437): CRITICAL **: Error while moving old database out of the way.
AppStream cache update failed.
```

What can I check for to solve this problem? The number which comes after the colon in appstreamcli varies, but the rest of the message is always the same.

Comment: you can try `sudo chmod -R 777 /var/cache/app-info/xapian/default` you should be able to do the update then ... This isn't a fix ... this may revert back and give you the same error next time you update ... but I ran into this on Ubuntu for Windows for a while and it was the only fix we could come up with ... it has since fixed itself .. well .. it doesn't happen anymore. So this should get you by at least .. but .. don't take it as a fix .. more of a work around.. I was never able to discover the actual cause :(

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I didn't do the trick. I'll keep trying..

Comment: hmm ok .. maybe it wasn't the same thing I was running into .. sorry it was my only idea on  this issue :(

Answer (score 8):

There is a wrong Symbolic Link ([confirmed bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/appstream/+bug/1601971)).

These commands solved the problem, in my case.

```
sudo mv /var/cache/app-info/xapian/default /var/cache/app-info/xapian/default_old
sudo mv /var/cache/app-info/xapian/default_old /var/cache/app-info/xapian/default
```

I think giving full permissions to a software database folder is not a good idea.

You may need to do this every time that you add a new repository.

Comment: Hi Carlos, can you link to the bug report in your answer?

Comment: Here's the bug report from 2016: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/appstream/+bug/1601971

Comment: Tested and worked: 2020-06-10. [This](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/appstream/+bug/1601971/comments/11) shows what worked in [this bug discussion thread](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/appstream/+bug/1601971). And this answer gives the gist of that.

Answer (score 8):

A. My case is solved with the command below :

```
$ sudo touch /var/cache/app-info/xapian/default
```

B. The error is as follows :

```
$ sudo apt update
...
** (appstreamcli:12092): CRITICAL **: Error while moving old database out of the way.
AppStream cache update failed.
...
All packages are up to date.
```

C. Environment :

```
Windows 10 Pro, 64 Bit + Ubuntu

$ uname -an
Linux Arthur 4.4.0-17134-Microsoft #345-Microsoft Wed Sep 19 17:47:00 PST 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```