# Run additional software on ubuntu live (temporalily)

Tags: 16.04, live-usb

The disk of my computer is corrupted. I plan to use Ubuntu to recover data on the disk.

I went to my friend's home and made a Ubuntu USB stick. I don't think the Ubuntu USB stick has a persistent storage portion.

My computer successfully boots from the Ubuntu USB stick, but my recovery requires additional software.

```
$ sudo apt-get install testdisk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package testdisk

$ sudo apt-get update
...                  
Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted Translation-en [2,272 B]                     
Fetched 3,789 kB in 12s (297 kB/s)                                                                             

** (appstreamcli:4232): CRITICAL **: Error while moving old database out of the way.
AppStream cache update failed.
Reading package lists... Done
```

[image]

apt-get reports error, I guess it's because the USB stick is kind of read-only mode?

I don't want to bother my friend again to make a persistent USB stick.

What is the easiest way to run additional software on Ubuntu Live?

Comment: Maybe try apt? I regularily use apt to install boot-repair from a ppa on a live-usb without trouble.

Comment: Unable to locate testdisk - https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=testdisk shows it's in 'universe' so did you enable that?  (it's enabled by default for flavors, not main Ubuntu; you also didn't specify the release so all are provided) https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu ; I wonder if you've missed in your edits all the messages as to your `update` error, but it'll work with a 'live' mode (I would check `dmesg` & system logs for clues if messages you cut were no help). Adding additional software is no issue, but the ram / has limits..

Comment: @guiverc Hi, I edited my post. My ubuntu is 16.04 for its slim size. I also uploaded a screenshot.

Comment: What program was used to make your Live USB? It might be possible to format a second USB as ext4, label the partition casper-rw and boot the first USB Persistent using the second USB to save the data in. If you need more info let me know which program was used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Installing testdisk for single use

You do not need persistence to (hopefully) run testdisk just once.

**Add universe repository**

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

**Update**

```
sudo apt-get update
```

**Install testdisk**

```
sudo apt-get install testdisk
```

**Run testdisk**

```
testdisk
```

Above works for me on balenaEtcher Live USB using Ubuntu 16.04.5 running on 4GB USB2 thumbdrive.

Comment: You are correct. I solved the failure of `sudo apt-get update` by https://askubuntu.com/a/1031555/703866